# python: problems converting dates to a different format and pasting it on to an excel cell

Tags: python, datetime

I am not sure if this is more of an excel question of datetime question

my input is the string i.e. '20200609' in YYYYmmdd format
I want to convert to dd/mm/YYYY format and paste to excel

Please see snippets of my codes below

```
extractDate = '20200609'
ws.Range('A18').Value = datetime.strptime(extractDate,'%Y%m%d').strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

now I would expect to see 9/6/2020 (i.e. 9th June 2020) in my excel cell 'A18', but what I see in my excel is 6/9/2020 i.e. 6th  September 2020. Any idea whats is going on here?. When I run it on my console it shows me correct date (i.e. 9/6/2020) so something going on when I paste the value to teh excel

thanks,

Comment: this is an excel issue. maybe there is an option in excel to change the date format

Comment: That is how excel recognizes the date format, the date format that you gave might be recognized as such in excel, so you can change the format in excel

Comment: thanks but not sure what setting I need to change, if I manually type date in excel It looks fine, but only when I paste using codes its incorrect!

Comment: "something going on when I paste the value" > yes | instead, try pasting it into notepad 1st.. then replace / with . (dot) , then copy again and paste to excel.. change the data into 3 column using text to column.. Say cell A1, A2, A3, have the value 9, 6 , 2020. then put `=DATE(A3,A2,A1)` will guarantee the correct date is inserted (as excel date format)

Comment: got it be an easier way, the above code works seamlessly on my Mac so needs to work on my windows as well I would think

Comment: Excel might also take that setting from the operating system - which could be different in your case